# how to debug wp8 app downloaded from store?

Tags: windows-phone-8, marmalade

I've made a game using marmalade sdk and AppEasy engine and it works when I test it on the device but after submitting to store and downloading it only shows splash screen and then terminates.
Is there a way to debug it? Android and ios both have tools to trace the console output, is there such a tool for wp8? I only found how to do that for apps deployed to the device locally but no way to debug downloaded apps :(

For my other game made in same framework (with same issue) there is a crash report on the dev center dashboard with error saying 'STACK_OVERFLOW_DATA' but that doesn't help much

also tried this (solution found in some other question):

```
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }

        string result = "nothing :(";
        IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (store.FileExists("iwtrace.txt"))
        {
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("iwtrace.txt", FileMode.Open, store))
            {
                using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    result = fileReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        EmailComposeTask task = new EmailComposeTask();
        task.To = "";
        task.Subject = "crash log " + e.ExceptionObject.Message;
        task.Body = result;
        task.Show();
    }
```

but it never get's to showing the email form

Comment: I am afraid you can't debug it as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way yet to debug retail version of WP8 apps especially which are made in Marmalade.
You can read more about that in the article explaining [how to test the retail version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj585401(v=vs.105).aspx).

According to the article you need to test the retail version via Visual Studio in case of Native C# app. I suppose even native XAML apps can't be debugged after downloading from store.

I've asked [almost similar question](https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/14289/how-to-get-debug-log-from-windows-phone-8.html) on Marmalade forums last year. The only way at that time was to use Windows Power tool or Visual Studio.

To test the function, run your code from Visual Studio in release mode and see if it crashes or not. That's the only thing you can do in this case as far as I know.

Comment: Yea, I tried running release build without debuging from visual studio and it works fine. Windows Power tool doesn't show apps downloaded from store so still no way to get the crash log